# Pin config for CIS scanner

Tags: integrated-circuit, pins, reverse-engineering

I've salvaged a linear scanner from an HP scanner cum printer. The scanner senor model is CA4B94. It's got two portions on a single flat ribbon cable. One is for the motor, so I guess it's safe to ignore that entirely. I need to use this sensor as a detector for scanning purposes.

Please guide me with how to start finding the pins on the ribbon cable and understanding their function. The IC is a custom with no details on it.

[image: The isolated 11 pins run into the custom IC][image: . Custom IC - with no details]

Comment: It sounds like you want to reverse engineer the IC chip output! It's probably easiest to dig really hard for documentation (clues) before you start. Then you can probably try probing around with a voltmeter/oscilloscope/logic analyzer.

Comment: I've got a voltmeter but lack logic analyser, I guess I can do that with an Arduino. Gonna build that first.